# How to get only part of word from column and remove everything before and after it using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following details column, with varying parameters. How can I get only `joblib` values? "The Place of joblib is not always the same, so I may bot be able to use substring count"

```
date:01/12/2014--**--joblib:[snbsd]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto

date:01/12/2014--**--joblib:[jinxthin]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto

date:01/12/2014--**--joblib:[snbserv]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto

date:01/12/2016--**--joblib:[sql12server]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto

date:01/12/2015--**--joblib:[stfmbinserx]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto

date:01/12/2011--**--joblib:[ftplikes]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto
```

Desired result:

```
snbsd
jinxthin
snbserv
sql12server
stfmbinserx
ftplikes
```

Comment: thanks but it does not answer my question. That post only has only one of the variable and he/she is getting the value from bracket. In this problem, I have to get rid of everything before and after joblib and get the value of bracket.

Comment: It's a general answer, you have to adapt it to your needs:
`SELECT SUBSTRING(str FROM 'joblib:\[(\w+)\]') FROM a;`
Get a look at Regular Expressions:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You go:

```
substring(substring(var1, position('joblib:' in var1)+8), 1, position(']' in substring(var1, position('joblib:' in var1)+8))-1)
```

replace var1 with column name containing Your string
With below You can try it out directly on PostgreSQL:

```
WITH myconstants (var1) as (
   values ('date:01/12/2014--**--joblib:[snbsd]--**--date_type:no_date--**--max_feat_values:ss,group_filters:[]--**--no_imp_phrases:1--**--variable_facets:auto')
)
SELECT substring(substring(var1, position('joblib:' in var1)+8), 1, position(']' in substring(var1, position('joblib:' in var1)+8))-1)  
FROM myconstants
```

Comment: Thank you! Still keeps the first bracket, but it works.

Comment: Then play around with ```position('joblib:' in var1)+8``` change to ```position('joblib:' in var1)+9```

Comment: Yes changed 8s to 9 to get rid of the extra "[". Thanks again!